# How to change values of integer array inside onPreviewFrame?

Tags: java, android

I have a main class:

```
MainActivity extends Activity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener
```

with the array:

```
private int[] test = new int[2];
```

When a button is pressed I save the picture on a file and it works, but also I want (before saving) calculate a measure on the buffer and see values changed on this array.

For this purpose I call from `MainActivity`:

```
mCameraManager.takeSnapshot(test);
```

In `CameraManager` I have:

```
public void takeSnapshot(int[] test) {
    SnapshotManager mng = new SnapshotManager(mContext, mCurrentTexture, mCamera,test);     
    mng.takeSnapshot();
}
```

And finally in `SnapshotManager` I have:

```
public class SnapshotManager implements Camera.PreviewCallback {    
private MainActivity mContext;
private SurfaceTexture mCameraTexture;
private Camera mCamera;
public int[] mtest;

public SnapshotManager(
        MAinActivity context,
        SurfaceTexture cameraTexture,
        Camera camera,
        int[] test) {

    mContext = context;
    mCameraTexture = cameraTexture;
    mCamera = camera;
    mtest = test;

    //test[0] = 1;
    //test[1] = 2;
}

public void takeSnapshot() {
    mCamera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(this);
}

public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // save picture ...
    mtest[0] = 1;
    mtest[1] = 2;
}
}
```

If I do in `SnapshotManager` changing to test, they are changed also in `MainActivity`, insted if I change in `onPreviewFrame mtest`, the results in `MainActivity` of test is always zero.

How it is possible to do modification inside `onPreviewFrame` to have the value of test changed? Test will be an elaboration of the data.

Thanks. Any help will be really appreciated.

Added: I also tried instead to pass test by argument to use it as return of the function takeSnapshot, but unfortunately it does not work the same.

Added: It seems that the function takeSnapshot return before entering in onPreviewFrame, so all modification I do inside onPreviewFrame are not "seen" in the MainActivity.

Comment: Your trivial example looks like it should work. However, I notice a few things. One, the types are different `byte[] data` != `int[] mtest`. Two, your arrays to `onPreviewFrame` would have to be sized exactly the same (because Arrays are not dynamic datastructures in Java). Finally, most graphics are usually in 2 dimensional arrays.

Comment: Sorry Elliot test is just an example. I need to elaborate data and obtain these two values (test[0] and test[1]) to use in the MainActivity.

Comment: If you mean what I think you mean when you say "elaborate", that will break your reference to the original `MainActivity` `test[]`. I think you'll find an `ArrayList` much easier to work with.

Comment: Yes Elliot my problem is that in MainActivity the values of test[] remain always zero. How can I overcome this problem? (I need an array of integer: two values was just an example)

Comment: I suggest you use an `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of your `int[]`.

Comment: Also tried your suggestion Elliot but does not work. 
It seems that the function takeSnapshot return before entering in onPreviewFrame, so all modification I do inside onPreviewFrame are not "seen" in the MainActivity. 
What I need is something like a wait function to wait for onPreviewFrame to finish before coming back.